# Compiling errors in C

Tags: c

Im having an issue for a program im making for computer science II class. Was wondering if you guys would help me out. Its been about 2 years since I took computer science I, so dont be to hard on me if its something easy.

anyway, this is the code i have;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

/*The purpose of this program is to be able to enter 4 numbers
and let the program tell you which number the the largest, which 
number is the smallest, and then multiply the first 3 numbers together 
and then divides by the 4th one. once doe it will print the results.
The main goal is to help you understand pointers*/

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d = 0;
    int result; 


    printf("Enter the 4 numbers"); //instructions
    scanf("%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d); //collects 4 numbers

    result = (a*b*c)/d;

    max(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result); //prints the max of the 4 numbers
    min(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result); //prints the min of the 4 numbers

    return 0;
}

void max(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result)
{
    if(a > b && a > c && a > d)
    {
        printf("The max is %d. ", a);
    }

    if(b > a && b > c && b > d)
    {
        printf("The max is %d. ", b);
    }

    if(c > a && c > b && c > d) 
    {
        printf("The max is %d. ", c);
    }

    if(d > a && d > b && d > c)
    {
        printf("The max is %d. ", d);
    }



}
void min (int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result)
{
    if(a < b && a < c && a < d)
    {
        printf("The min is %d. ", a);
    }

    if(b < a && b < c && b < d)
    {
        printf("The min is %d. ", b);
    }

    if(c < a && c < b && c < d)
    {
        printf("The min is %d. ", c);
    }

    if(d < a && d < b && d < c)
    {
        printf("The min is %d. ", d);
    }


}
void mul (int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result)
{
    printf("(a * b * c) / d = %d\n", result);
}
```

Here are the errors im getting;

```
lab1.c: In function 'main':
lab1.c:20:6: error: expected expression before 'int'
lab1.c:21:6: error: expected expression before 'int'
lab1.c: At top level:
lab1.c:26:6: warning: conflicting types for 'max' [enabled by default]
lab1.c:20:2: note: previous implicit declaration of 'max' was here
lab1.c:51:6: warning: conflicting types for 'min' [enabled by default]
lab1.c:21:2: note: previous implicit declaration of 'min' was here
```

Any help!?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a code dump with some errors. It shows no effort to solve the problem.

Comment: Thew initial portions of your code show that you know how to call a function in C. Why then did you dump these meaningless `max(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result)` lines in the middle of your code? What did yo try to do by these lines?

Comment: @Almo: Oh please.  It's a beginner who doesn't understand the errors.  Why would you assume he hasn't tried?  Yeesh, give the guy a break and help him out.  At least he posted his code and the error output.

Comment: SO is supposed to be a database of questions and answers, not a forum. Sorry if I take the site's official mission to heart.

Comment: @Almo: I've been trying to figure out my mistakes for the past 3 hours and i was able to correct about 70% of my errors myself. Yes i am new, and i dont fully understand c programming. Sorry to have wasted your time :-P

Answer (score 1):

```
max(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result); //prints the max of the 4 numbers
min(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result); //prints the min of the 4
```

Those are forward declarations of functions, not function calls, but you forgot the return types, hence the error.  To call your functions, use:

```
max(&a, &b, &c, &d, &result); //prints the max of the 4 numbers
min(&a, &b, &c, &d, &result); //prints the min of the 4
```

Next, you *will* need to forward declare those functions above where they are called (main):

```
void max(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result);
void min (int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result);

int main() {
    /* ... */
}
```

Finally, neither of your functions set the `result` variable.

Comment: Great! tyvm for the assistance! ill give that a try

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your function wrong

```
max(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *result);
```

Change it to

```
 max(&a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
```

Same for `min` function.

Comment: That's the smaller of his problems :-) OP also finds the smallest of the pointers, prints pointers as integers, and does other fun stuff with his code.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using data types inside the function call ?

You should do this:-

```
  max(&a, &b, &c, &d, &result) ;
```

and same for min as well

When calling the functions, just supply the arguments without the data type, alternatively you could do this:-

```
 int *pa =  &a ; 
 int *pb = &b ; 
 int *pc = &c ;
 int *pd = &d ; 
 int  *presult = &result ; 
 max(pa, pb, pc, pd, presult) ; 
 // similarly for min.
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given:

```
int a, b, c, d = 0;
```

probably isn't doing what you think it is. Try:

```
int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0;
```

Also, IDK if you did this because of a requirement for the assignment but it is completely pointless to pass int pointers around. They are no smaller than just copying the values to the function.

Also, passing a reference to result to these function is pointless. Just return result from the function.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given above are correct but as an advice Rather than passing pointers to the functions it would have been much easier to transfer the vaiables and use the variables in the desired functions.

Although it doesn't matter but u might also want to make result a floating point value as on division there is no guarantee that u always get perfect integer value(just a minor advice).